# NavigationDrawer Not working with Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have implemented Google Maps along with Navigation Drawer. There is an issue with google maps, when I place the fragment of Map below the Navigation Drawer, Map works perfectly but drawer hides behind the Navigation Drawer, And when I write Maps code before the Navigation Drawer then Navigation Drawer works perfectly but Map didn't work, I was unable to do zoom or move it around. Following is XML file where I have declared both of them.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
             android:name="com.example.muhammad.shopplus.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The `DrawerLayout` should be the parent view. Use this: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: @JaredBurrows It works. Thankyou man.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Dear please solve this problem also .NavigationDrawer is working fine when I swipe it comes out but when I try to move it back, it stuck their. I dont know how to do it. please help me out

Comment: You said it works and not it is stuck? what do you mean?