# Why does the Navigation Drawer stop working when I add GoogleMaps to my app?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I'm working on my first Android app which uses a Navigation Drawer and Google Maps. I want the Google Maps to show up as soon as the app opens, but I also want it to show up when "New Trip" in the Navigation Drawer is selected.

By itself, the Navigation Drawer works fine. But as soon as I add Google Maps in, nothing in the drawer opens to the correct layout when clicked anymore. I've tried to create a new Fragment for the map itself instead of putting it in MainActivity, but no luck. I've also followed several video tutorials on Creating a Nav Drawer and Adding GoogleMaps into an app, but none of them answer my question:

When adding Google Maps to an app that already has a Navigation Drawer, are you supposed to create a new MapActivity.java and map.xml? How do you make a map appear on `onCreate` in the MainActivity as well as later on when a selection is made in the Navigation Drawer?

I can't explain why my Navigation Drawer stops working when I haven't changed the `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)` in MainActivity:

```
package com.trippal.trippal;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    private static final double
            CSULA_LAT = 34.065207,
            CSULA_LNG = -118.170125,
            LASVEGAS_LAT = 36.126750,
            LASVEGAS_LNG = -115.165718;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (initMap()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            gotoLocation(CSULA_LAT, CSULA_LNG, 14);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Map not connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_new_trip_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new NewTripFragment())
                    .commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_saved_trip_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new SavedTripFragment())
                    .commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_saved_poi_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new SavedPOIFragment())
                    .commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_pref_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new PrefFragment())
                    .commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    // ***** map logic *****
    // checks if map service is connected
    public boolean servicesOK() {

        int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to mapping service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

        return false;
    }

    // initiates google map
    private boolean initMap() {

        if (mMap == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        }
        return (mMap != null);
    }

    // moves the camera location
    private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom){
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

    // hides softkey
    private void hideSoftKeyboard(View v){
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }

    // geo location
    public void geoLocate(View v) throws IOException {
        hideSoftKeyboard(v);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.map_editText_location);
        String searchString = tv.getText().toString();

        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);

        List<Address> list = gc.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);

        if (list.size() > 0){
            Address address = list.get(0);
            String locality = address.getLocality();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Found: " + locality, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            double lat = address.getLatitude();
            double lng = address.getLongitude();
            gotoLocation(lat, lng, 15);
        }
    }
}
```

content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.trippal.trippal.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/map_textView_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/map_textView_location"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/map_editText_location"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/map_textView_location"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/map_textView_location"
                android:ems="6"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/map_textView_location"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:onClick="geoLocate"
                android:text="@string/map_button_search" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Make your DrawerLayout and NavigationView as instance variables, i.e. declare them as global variable in the class. Initialize them only ones in the onCreate() method and use the same variable in all the methods.

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947211/navigationdrawer-not-working-with-google-maps

Comment: Thanks for the link. My navigation drawer shows up just fine. It's just not functional anymore. For instance, after I add Googlemaps, when I try to navigate to "Saved POIs" in the drawer, it doesn't take me to any page although I have it pointing to the saved_poi_layout. As soon as I take Googlemaps out, it works again.